# PySide2 drag & drop functionality does not work

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside2

I have this simple script which uses PySide2 although I tried the same script with PyQt5 with the same result. I am trying to drag & drop files onto my window and get their file path:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasUrls():
            e.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        for url in e.mimeData().urls():
            file_name = url.toLocalFile()
            print("Dropped file: " + file_name)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

On my system this does not allow drag & drop actions to this window. `dragEnterEvent` is never called. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your script works as expected (allows drag & drop and prints file path) on my computer with python 3.6.5 on Windows 7, tested with PySide2 5.11.2 and 5.12.0. What is your configuration?

Comment: @jpeg Thanks for trying it out, my configuration is Windows 10 (1809), Python 3.6.8, PySide2 5.12. I also tried with PySide2 5.11.2. It might be a Windows 10 issue maybe? My colleague also tried it on his computer with the same results.

Comment: Does drag and drop actually work for other applications at all on your system? A web search with for example `Drag and drop not working in windows 10` yields plenty of resources, one of them might help solving your problem...?

Comment: @jpeg Thanks, yes one of the solutions worked: disabling EnableLUA using regedit. But I don't understand why this is needed for PySide2 applications because drag & drop works on my other applications even when EnableLUA is enabled, for example I can open files in Sublime by just dragging without a problem.

Comment: Sounds great. Please consider adding your solution as answer and marking it as accepted. I don't understand either why it is needed for PySide2 under Windows 10 but not under Windows 7, one should probably ask Microsoft...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that it happens on some systems with Windows 10. The solution is to disable `EnableLUA` from registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Policies > System`

Change the key `EnableLUA` from `1` to `0`. Then restart your computer. Note that this will cause your system to not show any dialog if a program tries to change something on your system which might be a security issue.